# How to put Rails environment variable in apple-app-site-association file for universal links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ios-universal-links

So currently I have inside the public folder a file called "apple-app-site-association" with the content:

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"{#Rails.configuration.appID}","paths":"*"}]}}
```

Obviously the {#Rails.configuration.appID} is not being generated dynamically and is being output literally, but I would like it to be reading from the config file, where appID is defined. How can I go about this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to just add a route.

`get '/apple-app-site-association' => 'pages#apple_app_site_association'`

```rb
def apple_app_site_association
  render :json => {"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID": Rails.configuration.appID,"paths":"*"}]}}
end
```

You may need to do more than that, but that should at least get you moving in the right direction.

Update 2020: Typo in route path fixed

Comment: yeah, at least they'll have to define the controller

Comment: Went ahead and added the method to my application controller but I'm getting the error  'apple_app_site_assocation' could not be found for ApplicationController

Comment: add that method to your application_controller.rb then

Comment: Theres actually a typo within the example: 
pages#apple_app_site_assocation
should be
pages#apple_app_site_association

Comment: What about the .well-known directory here?

Comment: That typo had me scratching my head for 20 minutes.